# How to read complex json object data in ng-grid angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid for my requirement.So far i can access json object and can draw the grid.But the problem is that when json object is complex i can not fetch data from json.I have used `cellTemplate` property to display my custom rows.in here i have used card layout.(material design).My requirement is that i want to fetch each results according to `testExecutionPlanUid` and under `testCase` read values and draw card like below example.I am new to angularjs and appreciate any help.

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/zaeyxANdyPPevUaggBTj?p=preview)

**Json object need to show in ng-grid**

```
[
    {
        "testExecutionPlanUid": "d59f624b-2db6-42b8-802f-36a0bba95855",
        "testCase": [
            {
                "resultid": "859a88d5-6251-4d3a-97ba-dcba1c45f436",
                "testExecutionPlanUid": null,
                "taskid": null,
                "fteId": null,
                "testPlan": "Default suite",
                "testExecutionPlanFullName": null,
                "testScript": "B_create",
                "type": "REGRESSION",
                "env": "QA",
                "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
                "baseurl": null,
                "buildNo": "15.1.1",
                "buildInfo": null,
                "runtimeVersion": null,
                "executiontime": null,
                "time": "2015-04-18 09:59:54.405",
                "dateStatus": "6 months ago",
                "capabilities": null,
                "testExecutionPlanXml": null,
                "requestLog": null,
                "executionlog": null,
                "fileAttachments": 0,
                "attachements": null,
                "dataTable": null,
                "automator": null,
                "node": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "testExecutionPlanUid": "d59f624b-2db6-42b8-802f-36a0bba95895",
        "testCase": [
            {
                "resultid": "859a88d5-6251-4d3a-97ba-dcba1c45f436",
                "testExecutionPlanUid": null,
                "taskid": null,
                "fteId": null,
                "testPlan": "Default suite",
                "testExecutionPlanFullName": null,
                "testScript": "BcreatePO",
                "type": "REGRESSION",
                "env": "QA",
                "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
                "baseurl": null,
                "buildNo": "15.1.1",
                "buildInfo": null,
                "runtimeVersion": null,
                "executiontime": null,
                "time": "2015-04-18 09:59:54.405",
                "dateStatus": "6 months ago",
                "capabilities": null,
                "testExecutionPlanXml": null,
                "requestLog": null,
                "executionlog": null,
                "fileAttachments": 0,
                "attachements": null,
                "dataTable": null,
                "automator": null,
                "node": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can fetch values like this.

```
<span ng-repeat="testcase in row.entity.testCase">{{testcase.testScript}}{{$last ? "" : ","}}</span>
```

**Reference**
[Ng-grid insert several items to cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659660/ng-grid-insert-several-items-to-cell)